# How to create Save File Dialog Box in user control?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, controls

I want to open a file dialog box in user control. I used `using System.Windows.Forms`, but still I can't access SaveFileDialog class. Can anybody tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is that what you are trying to do? Post your reply to this comment if you have achieved what you wanted.

Comment: Sory I am replying late. But realy it is what i wannted to do. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use SaveFileDialog in asp.net (if I look at the tags of the question).

It seems you want to let the uset click on some button to download a file and prompt the user to save it.

If that is a correct assumption, see the accepted answer at [with just a plain html and js file, how can i force a link to an mp3 to download instead of just play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338616/with-just-a-plain-html-and-js-file-how-can-i-force-a-link-to-an-mp3-to-download)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=file>
```

or

```
<asp:FileUpLoad id="FileUpLoad1" runat="server" />
```

might be what you have in mind.  It will let the user upload a file as part of the POST.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.
I found solution for this and its working. I used HTTPHandler to download file on cliet side.